# Newbie visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Select Case used.Text
Case Is <= 30
pay = used * 120
Case Is > 30, Is <= 60
pay = used * 150
Case Is > 60, Is <= 90
pay = used * 190
End Select
```

EX:
    MR.A used 75m3 of water a month so he must pay:
    30 x 120 = 3600
    30 x 150 = 4500 
    15 x 15 = 2850
    and total : 10950

but my code doesnt right help me fix it im newbie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: You don't check 30 or 60.

Answer (score 1):

i'm also a newbie, sure this is a horrible way to code it but it seems to work...first off replace literals with variables to allow for changing requirements.  I didn't check many cases so this might not be exact but was fun to think thru the problem.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim pay As Double
Dim used As Double
Dim balance As Double
Dim BillingIncrement As Double
Dim FirstUnitPrice As Double
Dim SecondUnitPrice As Double
Dim MaxUnitPrice As Double

BillingIncrement = 30
FirstUnitPrice = 120
SecondUnitPrice = 150
MaxUnitPrice = 190

'put in loop to test various inputs for debug only
For used = 10 To 100 Step 5
Debug.Print "used ", used

If used <= BillingIncrement Then
    pay = used * FirstUnitPrice
  Else
    pay = BillingIncrement * FirstUnitPrice
    Debug.Print "first " & BillingIncrement & " units billed at 120"
    balance = used - BillingIncrement
    Debug.Print "balance ", balance

    If balance > BillingIncrement Then
        pay = pay + BillingIncrement * SecondUnitPrice
        Debug.Print "second " & BillingIncrement & " units billed at " & SecondUnitPrice

        balance = balance - BillingIncrement
        If balance > 0 Then
            pay = pay + balance * MaxUnitPrice
            Debug.Print balance, " units billed at " & MaxUnitPrice
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print balance, " billed at " & SecondUnitPrice
        pay = pay + balance * SecondUnitPrice
     End If
  End If

Debug.Print "Pay = ", pay

' a couple example test cases
If used = 40 Then
    If pay <> 5100 Then
        Debug.Print "error"
        Else: Debug.Print "ok so far"
    End If
End If
If used = 60 Then
    If pay <> 8100 Then
        Debug.Print "error"
        Else: Debug.Print "ok so far"
    End If
End If



'reset for next loop
pay = 0
balance = 0

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks or ur help ,but it seem not work on my vb6? i dunno why , should i add the new textbox and name it balance?